# How can I transform one column into 2 well aligned columns?

Tags: bash

If I use `pr -t-s" " --columns` for a list of countries, I have a messy output:

```
Senegal                  Sri Lanka
Serbia                  Sudan
Seychelles              Suriname
Sierra Leone                  Swaziland
Singapore                  Sweden
Sint Maarten                  Switzerland
Slovakia                  Syria
```

How can I have well 2 well aligned columns like this

```
Senegal                                            Sri Lanka
Serbia                                             Sudan
Seychelles                                         Suriname
Sierra Leone                                       Swaziland
Singapore                                          Sweden
Sint Maarten                                       Switzerland
Slovakia                                           Syria
```

Comment: Is it tab delimited between columns ?

Comment: I want the second column to be at a specific horizontal character number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` of `awk` command to format your files. Make your columns left aligned and insert few tabs in between. This should work where First column contains one word and second column onwards anything as part of second column.

```
awk '{x=$1;$1="";y=$0} {printf "%-10s%s%-10s\n", x,"\t\t\t",y}' col
Senegal                          Sri Lanka
Serbia                           Sudan
Seychelles                       Suriname
Sierra                           Leone Swaziland
Singapore                        Sweden
Sint                             Maarten Switzerland
Slovakia                         Syria
```

Answer (score -1):

The `column` command is what I was looking for.